# How to detect when Cocoa app switches from retina to non-retina screen?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, opengl, retina-display

I'm using a Macbook Pro Retina connected to a secondary *non-retina* display.  How do I detect when my app is moved to the *non-retina* display?

**EDIT:** This is an OpenGL app.  I'm using `-backingScaleFactor` in `NSScreen` to detect the scale factor of the screen.  I'm looking for a way to detect when this changes.

Comment: Why do you need this? It's not required. OS X will take care of re-adapting your UI when switching to a non-retina display.

Comment: MrAsterisco asks a good question: artwork should be supplied using either PDFs or using the FileName@2x naming scheme so Cocoa will automatically use the correct resolution. If you have a custom scenario, please edit your question and describe it in detail.

Comment: It's for a pure OpenGL app.  I need to be able to detect it so I can handle the drawing differently.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`NSWindow` will post `NSWindowDidChangeBackingPropertiesNotification`. The window's delegate will receive `-windowDidChangeBackingProperties:` if it implements that method. A view will receive `-viewDidChangeBackingProperties`.

See the section ["Handle Dynamic Changes in Window Resolution Only When You Must"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/HighResolutionOSX/CapturingScreenContents/CapturingScreenContents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012302-CH10-SW20) in Apple's [High Resolution Guidelines for OS X](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/HighResolutionOSX/).